# MS Excel loses focus when hitting certain shortcuts

Tags: microsoft-excel

Really struggling to fix this, every time I do Alt + H + O + W (column width), the first time it will take like 1 second before the little input box has focus (i.e. it's grayed out and I can't type on it), and the next time I hit the same shortcut it will just completely lose focus (i.e. I have to click on the little dialog box before being able to type a width).

Since I do a lot of financial analysis and need to do most of my Excel stuff quite quickly, this is a pain in the ass. Anyone has had this before? Any suggestions on how to fix? I already reinstalled Office to no avail.

Answer (score 1):

Discovered that Spotify was messing with Excel somehow. Be careful with that app!

Answer (score 0):

It's Google Drive app.  Maybe it's the Real Time Office Editing integration option.  I just quit and uninstalled Google Drive to be safe and shortcuts are back to normal.  This problem was affecting my excel productivity.

Comment: Can you distinguish this from the questioner's system which probably was not using Google Drive.